# Laravel: adding policy to stop other users visualizing other user's profiles

Tags: laravel

I need to block users from visualizing other users profiles I have the following in my web.php:

```
Route::get('companyuser/{id}',  [CompanyUserController::class, 'show'])
    ->middleware(['role:companyuser', 'can:show,user']);
```

I defined a policy

```
public function show(User $authenticatedUser, $user_model)
{
    return $authenticatedUser === $user_model->id ? Response::allow() : Response::deny();
}
```

and added it to the AuthServiceProvider

```
protected $policies = [
     'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
     User::class => CompanyUserPolicy::class,
];
```

But now the user is blocked from entering his own profile as well. What am I missing? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the policy show() method is comparing an object to an ID value. This will always return false because the `$authenticatedUser` variable is a `User` object, while `$user_model->id` is likely an integer. Using strict type comparison `===` an int can never be equal to an object:

```php
$authenticatedUser === $user_model->id
```

Instead the code should probably compare the id of both objects:

```php
$authenticatedUser->id === $user_model->id
```

Laravel Models also have a built-in method `public function is($model): bool` that can be used to verify two objects represent the same model (database record). Here is the same code using that method:

```php
$authenticatedUser->is($user_model)
```

The final solution might look like this:

```php
public function show(User $authenticatedUser, $user_model)
{
    return $authenticatedUser->is($user_model) ? Response::allow() : Response::deny();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer John, unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I tried to add some logging in the policy method and it seems it never gets there at all